# XCode - Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSTimer', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For a little background information, I am trying to develop an app where there will be a picture of a ball falling, to start anyway. I am using XCode 5 and iOS 7 development. I am trying to make the picture of the ball fall, but I keep getting this error in the viewcontroller.m: "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSTimer', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform" Here is the code that I am using:

Viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {

UIImageView *_Ball;
NSTimer *moveObjectTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *_Ball;
```

Viewcontroller.m:

```
@synthesize _Ball;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

moveObjectTimer - [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self
selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) moveObject {
_Ball.center = CGPointMake(_Ball.center.x, _Ball.center.y + 6);
}
```

If anyone can help me with the issue I am having, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank You!

Comment: Isn't it because you wanted to say `=`, not `-`?

Comment: Voting to close - it looks like a "find a typo" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with this code:

```
moveObjectTimer - [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self
selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You put `-` instead of `=`

Change the above code to :

```
moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self
selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem :) If by chance you were curious, I am a beginner to objective-c, so I am not perfect with stuff, I am essentially developing one of the worlds most simple and made app, but it is a way to start! Thanks again!

Comment: @doglover129: Don't worry, I faced similar situations, when I started my career. Best of luck for your future :)